# Jquery DIV click color change

Tags: jquery, click

I have a simple JQuery script as:

```
$('.pane-hover').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children().animate({backgroundColor: "#fff"}, 200 );
});
$('.pane-hover ').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children().animate({backgroundColor: "#e4e4e4"}, 200 );
});
```

What this does (using Jquery Color) is when you mouse into the div, it turns the background white, and leaving the div turns it back to its normal colour. There are multiple .pane-hover classes.

What I want to do, is activate the animate on click now - so that when you click the div, it turns the background white, but when you click on another div (same class) it reverts the other one back to its normal colour, and in turn makes the new div you clicked on, background white. So essentially, only one div ever has the background white.

Any idea on how to do this?

A sample of the existing HTML:

```
<div class="pane pane-hover pane-history" id="pane4">
<div class="scroll-pane">
    <div class="title title-empty"></div>
    <div class="scroll-pane-inner">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <p>Text.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-divider"></div>
</div></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show your html code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.pane-hover ').click(function(){
  $('.pane-hover').removeClass('animatedColor');
  $(this).addClass('animatedColor');
});
```

Also note make the `.pane` have a bg and the inside elements don't add a BG to them. Then your code is much more simple.

CSS

```
.animatedColor{
   background:#fff!important;
   transition:1s;
   -webkit-transition:1s;
   -moz-transition:1s;
   -o-transition:1s;
 }
```

Add this to the default color for a transition back to default color class `.pane`

```
     transition:1s;
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    -moz-transition:1s;
    -o-transition:1s;
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eh7E7/1/)

Comment: Not a problem if you like, don't forget upvote and mark answer as correct. Thanks